# Numbering group according changement value in a column with data.table (R)

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to do something very basic with data.table but I don't how to do this!

I have this data :

```
test <- data.table(exo = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1), number = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), remark = c("OK","OK","KO","KO","OK","OK","OK"))
  
   exo number remark
1:   1      1     OK
2:   1      2     OK
3:   1      3     KO
4:   1      4     KO
5:   1      5     OK
6:   1      6     OK
7:   1      7     OK
8:   1      8     KO
```

And I would like to number groups (very simple form is`test[ , indic_num := .GRP, by = .(exo, remark)]`) but I would like to consider in indic_num if I encounter a changement in remark : it is a new group.

So, desired output :

```
   exo number remark indic_num
1:   1      1     OK         1
2:   1      2     OK         1
3:   1      3     KO         2
4:   1      4     KO         2
5:   1      5     OK         3
6:   1      6     OK         3
7:   1      7     OK         3
8:   1      8     KO         4
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rleid` for `remark` so every change is considered as a new group.

```
library(data.table)
test[ , indic_num := .GRP, by = .(exo, rleid(remark))]
test

#   exo number remark indic_num
#1:   1      1     OK         1
#2:   1      2     OK         1
#3:   1      3     KO         2
#4:   1      4     KO         2
#5:   1      5     OK         3
#6:   1      6     OK         3
#7:   1      7     OK         3
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`, we can use `cur_group_id`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
test %>% 
     group_by(exo, grp = rleid(remark)) %>%
     mutate(indic_num = cur_group_id()) %>%
     ungroup %>%
     select(-grp)
# A tibble: 7 x 4
#    exo number remark indic_num
#  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>      <int>
#1     1      1 OK             1
#2     1      2 OK             1
#3     1      3 KO             2
#4     1      4 KO             2
#5     1      5 OK             3
#6     1      6 OK             3
#7     1      7 OK             3
```

---

With `data.table`, we could also do (assuming 'exo' is ordered)

```
test[, indic_num := rleid(exo, remark)]
test
#   exo number remark indic_num
#1:   1      1     OK         1
#2:   1      2     OK         1
#3:   1      3     KO         2
#4:   1      4     KO         2
#5:   1      5     OK         3
#6:   1      6     OK         3
#7:   1      7     OK         3
```